# Why does Harry hide under the bed?

Tags: plot-explanation, kiss-kiss-bang-bang

In “Kiss Kiss Bang Bang” (2005), Harry (Robert Downey Jr.) awakens in the back of a car in the garage of an unknown house. He walks in, calling for help and saying he has a medical issue (he earlier lost his finger). Then he hears a man and woman talking and dives under a bed.

He had been looking for people but, once he finds them, he hides. He has never met the woman and there is no sign that he recognizes the man’s voice. Why does he hide?